# Simulator able to run SwitchCase in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming

I am trying to run my circuit which is the following on a simulator. However, when I want to execute this on almost all the simulators the following error pops up:

"The control-flow construct 'switch_case' is not supported by the backend.". I will let you informed as soon as possible"

My code is:

````
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
from ibm_quantum_widgets import *
from qiskit import *
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute,  Aer
from qiskit.result import marginal_counts
from qiskit.providers.ibmq.job import job_monitor
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Sampler, Estimator, Session, Options
from math import pi

service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")
provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
qreg = QuantumRegister(4)
creg = ClassicalRegister(6)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qreg, creg)
qc.x(qreg[0])
qc.x(qreg[1])
qc.x(qreg[2])
qc.measure([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])

with qc.switch(creg) as case:
    with case(7):
        qc.x(qreg[3])


qc.measure(qreg[3], creg[3])

 
job = execute(qc, backend = backend, shots = 1000)
results = job.result()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Qiskit Aer (version 0.13) supports [`SwitchCaseOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.SwitchCaseOp.html). So, if it's OK to run your circuit locally, you can use Aer simulators:

```
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

backend = AerSimulator()
qc = transpile(qc, backend=backend)
job = backend.run(qc)
results = job.result()
```

Comment: it still comes up with the same error: The control-flow construct 'switch_case' is not supported by the backend."

Comment: Do you have Qiskit Aer version 0.13?